# regex to check for few special characters in textarea

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi I have been trying to check if there is any ? or * present in the textarea but unable to get the count

my try

```
if($('textarea').val().match(/\**\?*/).length){
   //do something
   console.log("* or ? not allowed");
}
```

test case

```
some word ????? ***** 
some*****
"*" "?"
"?"
```

"*"

it has to be able to check any possible ? or * present in the textarea.

Comment: You need a global flag if you want all matches.

Comment: Try following regular expressioin: `/[*?]/g`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `[*?]` as a pattern. It matches `*` or `?`. (`*`, `?` loses its special meaing inside `[...]` and matches literally.)

Using [`RegExp.prototype.test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test), you don't need to count matches.

```
if (/[*?]/.test($('textarea').val()) {
   // do something
   console.log("* or ? not allowed");
}
```

---

```
/[*?]/.test('hello world')   // => false
/[*?]/.test('hello * world') // => true
/[*?]/.test('hello world?')  // => true
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want go with `match` function then you can do just as below

```
if($('textarea').val().match(/[*?]/g).length > 0){
   //do something
   console.log("* or ? not allowed");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To check for text that contains a question mark or asterisk `[\?*]{1,}`